# Save emails to daily folders

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to create a macro which will save emails to a folder that is created locally on my hard drive. The folder is created daily through a batch file that was written. The folder name format will be mm-dd-yyyy. My goal is to save all the emails that come in each day to their corresponding folders. For examples, all emails that come in today get saved to a folder named 05-07-2015. Here is the code that I have so far.

```
Public Sub SaveMsgs(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
  Dim sPath As String
  Dim dtDate As Date
  Dim sName As String
  Dim enviro As String
  Dim sSender As String
  Dim strFolder As String
  Dim strNewFolder As String
  Dim save_to_folder As String

  enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))

  sName = Item.Subject
  ReplaceCharsForFileName sName, "_"

  sSender = Item.Sender

  dtDate = Item.ReceivedTime
  sName = sSender & " - " & sName & ".msg"

  strNewFolder = Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy ")
  strFolder = "C:\IT Documents\" & daymonthyr & strNewFolder

  If Len(Dir(strFolder, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
   MkDir (strFolder)
  End If

  save_to_folder = strFolder


  'FolderCreate = "C:\IT Documents\" & Format(Now, "mm-dd-yyyy ") & "\"

  'If Not FSO.FolderExists(FolderCreate) Then
  'FSO.CreateFolder (FolderCreate)
  'End If

'set the destination path
 ' sPath = "C:\IT Documents\" & Format(Now, "mm-dd-yyyy ") & "\"
  For Each Item In Outlook.ActiveExplorer.Selection

  Debug.Print sName
  Item.SaveAs save_to_folder & sName

  Next

  Set Item = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub ReplaceCharsForFileName(sName As String, _
  sChr As String _
)
 sName = Replace(sName, "/", sChr)
 sName = Replace(sName, "\", sChr)
 sName = Replace(sName, ":", sChr)
 sName = Replace(sName, "?", sChr)
 sName = Replace(sName, Chr(34), sChr)
 sName = Replace(sName, "<", sChr)
 sName = Replace(sName, ">", sChr)
 sName = Replace(sName, "|", sChr)
End Sub
```

So far the script is almost running the way it is supposed to be. The emails are being saved to the IT Documents folder, but it is not being saved to the corresponding daily folder. What modifications would need to be made. I am not sure right now what I would have to change. Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are missing the dash between the filename and the last folder.

After adding `& "\"` behind `strFolder = "C:\IT Documents\" & daymonthyr & strNewFolder` it works for me.

Comment: I actually just noticed that about 15minutes ago as I took a step back and reread through my code. Thank you very much for your help @Kay